# Ошибка с вычислениями с введеными пользователем данными

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    var rub = prompt('Введите сумму в рублях');
    var usd = 57;
    var eur = 62;
    alert('В долларах: ' + rub/usd +
    ' В евро: ' + rub/eur);
</script>
```

Comment: У меня всё работает без ошибок, что вводите в prompt?

Comment: Сделайте parseInt(rub)

Answer (score 1):

В принципе код рабочий:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
  var rub = prompt('Введите сумму в рублях');
  var usd = 57;
  var eur = 62;
  alert('В долларах: ' + rub / usd +
    ' В евро: ' + rub / eur);
</script>
```

ошибку выдаст, если Вы введете туда не число, либо в качестве разделителя используете запятую (вместо точки). Можно сделать так, через [`parseFloat`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) совместно с [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) и попутно заменим запятую на точку:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
  do {
    var rub = parseFloat(window.prompt("Введите сумму в рублях", "").replace(",", "."));
  } while (isNaN(rub));
  var usd = 57;
  var eur = 62;
  alert('В долларах: ' + rub / usd +
    ' В евро: ' + rub / eur);
</script>
```

В силу своей специфики, метод `parseFloat` будет преобразовывать в число с плавающей точкой по своим правилам, к примеру:

```
var a = parseFloat("10") + "<br>";
var b = parseFloat("10.00") + "<br>";
var c = parseFloat("10.33") + "<br>";
var d = parseFloat("34 45 66") + "<br>";
var e = parseFloat(" 60 ") + "<br>";
var f = parseFloat("40 years") + "<br>";
var g = parseFloat("He was 40") + "<br>";
```

Результатом будет следующее:

```
10
10
10.33
34
60
40
NaN
```

Нужно учитывать, к примеру, что при вводе вот такой строки **40 years** получим в результате **40**.

Comment: почему идет предложение parseInt?